# Python - how to convert CSV to JSON and choose which columns to drop or put in front?

Tags: python, json, csv

I have example CSV file:

```
zipcode,firstname,lastname,email
12345,mike,alson,mike@m.com
54321,joe,don,joe@j.com
```

Need to create output file in this format:

```
SET 12345 '{"firstname": "mike", "lastname": "alson", "email": "mike@m.com"}'
SET 54321 '{"firstname": "joe", "lastname": "don", "email": "joe@j.com"}'
```

How to achieve this?

I started with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv, json
csvreader = csv.reader(open('data.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
data = []
for row in csvreader:
    r = []
    for field in row:
        if field == '': field = None
        else: field = unicode(field, 'ISO-8859-1')
        r.append(field)
    data.append(r)
jsonStruct = {
    'header': data[0],
    'data': data[1:]
}
open('data.json', 'wb').write(json.dumps(jsonStruct))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your rows into a [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), then write the zip code separately with a serialized JSON formatted string from [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) of the remaining elements:

```
from csv import DictReader
from json import dumps

with open("rows.csv") as csv_file, open("output.txt", mode="w") as out_file:
    csv_reader = DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        zipcode = row["zipcode"]
        rest = {k: v for k, v in row.items() if k != "zipcode"}
        out_file.write("SET %s '%s'\n" % (zipcode, dumps(rest)))
```

**output.txt:**

```
SET 12345 '{"firstname": "mike", "lastname": "alson", "email": "mike@m.com"}'
SET 54321 '{"firstname": "joe", "lastname": "don", "email": "joe@j.com"}'
```

**Note:** As of Python3.6, `DictReader` returns rows of [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), which will maintain order when writing to the file. For lower versions, you will need to handle this manually.